# Is the integral $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(\ln{x})^{3/2}} \ dx$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Setting $t=\ln{x}$ I get $$\int_{\ln{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{3/2}} \ dt.$$

It is well know that  $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{p}} \ dx=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    \text{convergent if} &p > 1& \\
    \text{divergent if} &p\leq1& \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

But my integral starts from $\ln(2)<1$. Can I still apply this p-test and conclude that my original is convergent since $3/2>1?$

Comment: Do you know the definition of what it means for $\int_a^{\infty}$ to be convergent? Do you see how to relate $\int_1^{\infty}$ and $\int_{\ln 2}^{\infty}$ through a slight difference?

Comment: If it is convergent from 1 to infinity, then it is convergent from ln2 to infinity.

Comment: @user296602 - It means that the integral, once evaluated, will obtain a finite value. No not really.

Comment: Not really, it's a statement about a particular **limit**. Namely, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_a^t$ must be a real number. Now you need to related $\int_1^t$ and $\int_{\ln 2}^t$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\int_{\ln 2}^\infty=\int^1_{\ln 2}+\int_1^\infty$. Now consider the two integrals separately. In particular for the first one, you have a Riemann integral of a continuous function over a closed interval.

To make the above argument rigorous when needed, go back to the definition:
$$
\int_a^\infty f(x)\ dx= \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\ dx.
$$

---

[Added:]
You can of course replace the $1$ in $\int_1^\infty$ of your $p$-test by any *positive* real number, which can be proved by essentially the argument above.

Comment: Yes... ofcourse. This was a nice way of showing it.

Comment: @Parseval: So? $   $

Comment: So in general this is true: $$\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{p}} \ dx=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    \text{convergent if} &p > 1& \\
    \text{divergent if} &p\leq1& \\
  \end{array}
, \text{where} \ \  \ a>0\right.$$